# Knockout with DataTables on HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, datatables

I have a HTML table that works fine **without** DataTables.

However, I want to implement DataTables so that I can use the filtering/search functionality and also add/remove columns.

How do I get it working with Knockout?

```js
var ViewModel = function() {

$('#myTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: this.taskRecords()
        }
    });

this.taskRecords = ko.observableArray([
{
 EntityCode: "name",
  EntityName: "name desc23",
  TagName: "L1",
  TaskList: [
   {
     TaskName: "TaskABC",
      TaskRecordList: [
       { 
         StatusFlagName: "OK"
        },
        { 
         StatusFlagName: "TEST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     TaskName: "TaskDEF",
      TaskRecordList: [
       { 
         StatusFlagName: "Error"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]);
  
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Entity Code</th>
                    <th>Entity name</th>
                    <th>Control Level</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecords">
                <tr class="ui-state-default">
                    <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                    <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityName"></td>
                    <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: TagName"></td>
                    <!--ko foreach: TaskList-->
                    <td>
                        <div data-bind="text: TaskName"></div>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <!--ko foreach: TaskRecordList-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-bind="text: StatusFlagName"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--/ko-->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <!--/ko-->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Have you worked through the knockout-specific samples page from the DataTables documentation?

Comment: Did you solve your problem @kevin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

It looks like you are trying to bind the data twice:

1. With knockout in the HTML
2. With DataTable ajax url

And there is also another problem: DataTable does not like to add table columns without corresponding header.

## Solution

I got it to work with two modifications:

a. No data binding with DataTable, just init with:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
 responsive: true
});
```

b. Add `<th>Tasks</th>` to the table header

Complete solution: https://codepen.io/DonKarlssonSan/pen/mMVvME/

Comment: In the example given apply a search breaks the table by hiding all rows, event after removing the search text